# How to Access a Key In a dictionary From another script.

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to know how to access keys in a dictionary in another script. Is it possible. I have two scripts and I want to know is it possible. I have added keys to the dictionary, I want to knowhow to access them.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vuforia
{
public class ZoneDictonary : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Vector3 Zone1V;
    public Vector3 Zone2V;
    public Vector3 Zone3V;
    public Vector3 Zone4V;
    public Vector3 Zone5V;

    void Start()
    {
        Dictionary<Vector3, bool> isZoneEmpty = new Dictionary<Vector3, bool> ();
        isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone1V, true);
        isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone2V, true);
        isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone3V, true);
        isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone4V, true);
        isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone5V, true);
    }
}
}
```

Heres the other script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vuforia
{
public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{
    ZoneDictonary Zd;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject ZD = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Zone Manager");
        Zd = ZD.GetComponent<ZoneDictonary> ();


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you will have to expose your dictionary as a public member of your ZoneDictonary class using the `public` keyword.

I would recommend exposing it as a property and keeping the variable private rather than exposing just the variable, however.  There are numerous reasons for this.  [This answer on PSE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/143739/157774) list several in detail.

```
private Dictionary<Vector3, bool> _isZoneEmpty = new Dictionary<Vector3, bool> ();

public Dictionary<Vector3, bool> IsZoneEmpty { 
    get
    {
        return _isZoneEmpty;
    }
    set 
    {
        _isZoneEmpty = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a slight scope problem, but heres how you access your keys:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vuforia
{
    public class ZoneDictonary : MonoBehaviour 
    {   
        public Vector3 Zone1V;
        public Vector3 Zone2V;
        public Vector3 Zone3V;
        public Vector3 Zone4V;
        public Vector3 Zone5V;

        // Dictionary must be here to access from outside of this script
        public Dictionary<Vector3, bool> isZoneEmpty = new Dictionary<Vector3, bool> ();

        void Start()
        {
            isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone1V, true);
            isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone2V, true);
            isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone3V, true);
            isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone4V, true);
            isZoneEmpty.Add (Zone5V, true);
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vuforia
{
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        ZoneDictonary Zd;

        void Start()
        {
            GameObject ZD = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Zone Manager");
            Zd = ZD.GetComponent<ZoneDictonary> ();

            foreach(Vector3 key in Zd.isZoneEmpty.Keys)
            {
                //do something with keys
            }
        }
    }
}
```